Cannot load Swagger page from new API locally
I'm using Visual Studio 2022, I have a new ASP.NET Core 8.0 Web API project. I removed all traces of the example weather forecast that was loaded when I created the project, but now when I debug my application, I get the following error:

This localhost page can't be found.
No web page was found for the web address: https://localhost:7088/swagger

I also manually adjusted the URL but still get the error

No web page was found for the web address: https://localhost:7088/api/present

From what I can see, this setup is caused by incorrect settings in either the controller class, launchsettings.json or program.cs.
My controller code looks like this:
Controller class
[ApiController]
Route("api/[controller]")]
public class PresentController(IPresentsService _presentsService) : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Produces(MediaTypeNames.Application.Json)]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(IEnumerable<PresentDto>), StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
    public async Task<IEnumerable<PresentDto>> GetAllPresentsAsync()
    {
        return await _presentsService.GetAllPresentsAsync();
    }
}

My launchSettings.json looks like this:
"https": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7088;http://localhost:5030",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
}

My Program.cs looks like this:
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddControllers();

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddScoped<IPresentsRepository, PresentsRepository>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IPresentsService, PresentsService>();

builder.Services.AddDbContext<PresentsDbContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseNpgsql(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("PresentsDb"));
});

builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();

builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API V1");
    c.RoutePrefix = "";
});

app.Run();

Can somebody please explain what I am doing wrong? I have tried a few variations with the likes of Swashbuckle too, SwaggerUI etc but I have not had any luck.


This localhost page can't be found.
No web page was found for the web address: https://localhost:7088/swagger

The reason why you face the error is you set a RoutePrefix  to the swagger path, but you still use the old one, you should remove the  c.RoutePrefix = "";, then the path(https://localhost:7088/swagger) is right.

No web page was found for the web address: https://localhost:7088/api/present

Besides, inside the your program.cs, you removed the app.UseSwagger() and app.MapControllers(); , this will cause your second error, there is no route for the api controller and the swagger middelware will not generate the swagger json .
The right codes should as below:
var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API V1");

});
app.MapControllers();
app.Run();


Thanks for mention it, I forget to see your service, you are right, you need also add the related service like below:
builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());

builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();


Thanks Brando, I did receive an error after making these changes. I will post as an answer so it can be read more clearly than in this reply.

Brando's changes helped massively but I did have this error:
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.ISwaggerProvider' while attempting to Invoke middleware 'Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware'.

To resolve this I also added the builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen() line in the Program.cs code, as shown below.
builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());

builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

My application is now loading the swagger page correctly.

Thanks for mention it, I forget to see your service, you are right, you need also add the related service, please check my update answer. Besides, if you feel my reply help  you, please mark it . Thanks.
